# Does military background enhance personal productivity?

Tags: personality, performance, io-psychology, military-psychology

Is there any research investigating the effect (or correlation) of a military background of a person on his productivity, effectiveness and other characteristics?

It is often casually claimed that a person with a military background is more disciplined, hardworking and so on, but it is interesting to find out whether it is has a scientific proof.

There some other supporting reasons like that Harvard accepts a lot of people with a military background or many of them succeed in the business world.

See also the same question on [Productivity Stack Exchange](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/9690/does-military-background-enhance-productivity)

Comment: I think you'll get  different answer on this site to productivity.SE, but please don't post to multiple forums without at least acknowledging that you have done so. I've added the link to your other question.